# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded Neo4j

Tags: windows, import, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-shell

I am working on Neo4j project, I am trying a cypher file which contains 8237 cypher query. I tried using neo4j-shell for the import : `neo4j-shell -file <file path>`, as I encountered stackoverflow error I tried to increase the stack size by using -Xss using different sizes but it seems not working for me
is there someone who have any idea on what the problem could be

Specification: windows 10, 8Go RAM jre 8, Neo4j 3.0.7

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask.

Comment: What is the general form of the query? Are you saying that there are 8237 separate Cypher statements? If so try running them across multiple transactions instead of in a single transaction. See [the docs for info on transaction control with `neo4j-shell`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-commands.html#_transactions)